# Как сделать ресайз колонок бутстрапа курсором?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не ресейзится размер колонок при перетягивании хендлера?
Код ниже.

```js
resizeColumns()

function resizeColumns() {
  var wrapper = document.querySelector('.row');
  var box = null;
  var isHandlerDragging = false;
  var boxAminWidth = 60;
  var new_width = 0,
    current_width = 0;

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    // If mousedown event is fired from .handler, toggle flag to true
    if (e.target.classList.contains('drag-handler')) {
      isHandlerDragging = true;
      box = e.target;
    }

  });

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    // Don't do anything if dragging flag is false or 
    if (!isHandlerDragging) {
      return false;
    }

    // save the current box width
    current_width = window.getComputedStyle(box).width;
    console.log('current_width :', current_width);

    // check the minimum width
    if ((new_width = e.clientX - box.offsetLeft - 8) >= boxAminWidth) {
      box.style.width = new_width + 'px';
      
      console.log('new_width :', new_width);
    }

    // make sure the boxs dont go past the wrapper, aka: the overflow effect
    //if they do, we recover the last width of the current box to keep the boxs inside the wrapper.
    if (wrapper.lastElementChild.offsetLeft + wrapper.lastElementChild.offsetWidth > wrapper.offsetWidth) {
      box.style.width = current_width;
    }

  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    // Turn off dragging flag when user mouse is up
    isHandlerDragging = false;
  });
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.col {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.position-relative {
    position: relative !important;
}


.row .panel {
  /* Allow box to grow and shrink, and ensure they are all equally sized */
  /* flex: 1 1 auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  */
}

.panel:first-child::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -5px;
  z-index: 999;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: inset rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) -3px -3px 8px, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 3px 3px 8px, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 3px 3px 8px -3px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel position-relative drag-handler col">
    Cras sagittis. Suspendisse nisl elit, rhoncus eget, elementum ac, condimentum eget, diam. Ut leo. Praesent blandit laoreet nibh.
  </div>
  <div class="panel position-relative col">
    Cras sagittis. Suspendisse nisl elit, rhoncus eget, elementum ac, condimentum eget, diam. Ut leo. Praesent blandit laoreet nibh.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У `row` потрите стиль `flex-wrap: wrap;`, а `<div class="panel... col">` удалите класс `col`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас была проблема в использовании flex, оно и растягивало блоки, задавая размер.  А значение свойства `width` игнорируется. Можно сделать через `flex-grow` и `flex-shrink`, но по старинке проще.

```js
let sizer = document.querySelector('.sizer');
let sizerButtons = 0;
sizer.onmousedown=e=>{
  sizerButtons = 1;
};

window.onmouseup = window.onblur = ()=>{
  sizerButtons = 0;
}

window.onmousemove=e=>{
  if(!sizerButtons) return;
  const dx = e.movementX;
  const getWidth = el => el.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const leftPanel = sizer.previousElementSibling;
  const oldWidth = getWidth(leftPanel);
  const newWidth = oldWidth + dx;
  leftPanel.style.width = newWidth + 'px';  
};
```

```css
.left{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  user-select: none;
} 

.right {
  padding-left: 40px;
  user-select: none;
}

.sizer {
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: inset rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) -3px -3px 8px,
              inset rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 3px 3px 8px, 
                    rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 3px 3px 8px -3px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel left">
    Cras sagittis. Suspendisse nisl elit, rhoncus eget,  
    elementum ac, condimentum eget, diam. Ut leo.
    Praesent blandit laoreet nibh.
  </div>
  <div class="sizer"></div>
  <div class="panel right">
    Cras sagittis. Suspendisse nisl elit, rhoncus eget, 
    elementum ac, condimentum eget, diam. Ut leo.
    Praesent blandit laoreet nibh.
  </div>
</div>
```